# (Continued) How to compute E[log(X)] when X follows a beta distribution?

Tags: probability, expected-value, beta-function

I found an asnwer to my question on the site : [Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085184/how-to-compute-e-logx-when-x-follows-a-beta-distribution/2085200#2085200?newreg=41ce2fc5bba34826beef88ddf0f081dc).

It is a very nice answer but I still wonder: how do we get between those two lines?

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \ln x \,\frac{ x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\,dx \\[4pt]
&= \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)} \, \int_0^1 \frac{\partial x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\partial \alpha}\,dx \\[4pt]
\end{align}

Thanks,

Comment: it follows from $\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial \alpha}=\ln x\cdot x^{\alpha}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can take $\frac{1}{B(\alpha , \beta)}$ out of the integral because $B(\alpha , \beta)$ is constant with respect to x.

Then, use the fact that

$\frac{\partial x^{\alpha -1}}{\partial \alpha}=\ln x\cdot x^{\alpha -1}$

to obtain

$\frac{\partial x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\partial \alpha} = \ln(x) \, \cdot x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} $

Within the integral.